# Error: fail readDirectory() errno=13 by DownloadFolder (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app for android. I use Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0). I get an error, if i am trying to get the files from the Download folder. But i am able to get the absolutPath of the Download folder. I will show you at first the code, which causes an error afterwards the error.

**CODE:**

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.main_folder) {
        File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        Log.i("","" +file.getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            for(File f : file.listFiles()) {       //This line cause an error
                Log.i("file: ","" +f.getName());  
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("","" +e.getCause() + " " +e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Manifest:**

- android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
- android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">

> **ERROR**:
>
> - com.cr_itservice.frarota E/File﹕ fail readDirectory() errno=13
> - com.cr_itservice.frarota E/﹕ null Attempt to get length of null array

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Log the result of file.exists() and file.getAbsolutePath().  Show your permissions in **exact** context of how you have them in your manifest (and you should never have both, as write implies read).

Comment: **file.exists()** returns false and for **file.getAbsolutePath()** as stated above. And as error i get the same like above. I'm desperating...

Comment: If file.exists() returns false, try file.mkdir()   You still have not shown the output of file.getAbsoutePath()

Comment: Oh sorry, it outputs the following **/storage/emulated/0/Download**

Comment: boolean state = file.mkdir();

Log.i("","" +state);   //This line outputs false

Comment: mkdir() returns true only if the directory did not previously exist and it has been created, it, it will only be true once.  The more important question is what exists() subsequently returns.   Another possibility is that the external storage is unavailable on your device - if it is an sdcard it could potentially be removed or USB mounted, though that would seem less likely on a recent device than an android 1.x or 2.x one.

Comment: **exists()** returns true... 
I didn't catch your last advice, can you explain it more in detail please...

Comment: Now that exists() returns true (as opposed to false before) it should work.  The mkdirs() method will only return true when it actually ends up creating the directory, but false when it no longer needs to because the directory already exists.

Comment: But i'm not still able to access to the folder. How can i realize it??

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem.